# InvalidType: Invalid operation is performed

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder, chainer

I am trying to write a stacked autoencoder. Since this a stacked autoencoder we need to train the first autoencoder and pass the weights to the second autoencoder. So during training we need to define train_data_for_next_layer. Here I am getting error:

```
InvalidType: 
Invalid operation is performed in: LinearFunction (Forward)

Expect: x.shape[1] == W.shape[1]
Actual: 784 != 250
```

I am having issue with the last line. Is this problem due to incorrect model layer, I want to know what is the issue here. I have faced this problem several times before and any detailed explanation is welcome. The code is as follows:

```
class AutoEncoder(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self, n_in, n_out, activation='relu', tied=True):
        if tied:
            super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__(
                l1 = L.Linear(n_in, n_out)
            )
            self.add_param('decoder_bias', n_in)
            self.decoder_bias.data[...] = 0
        else:
            super(AutoEncoder, self).__init__(
                l1 = L.Linear(n_in, n_out),
                l2 = L.Linear(n_out, n_in)
            )
        self.tied = tied
        self.n_in = n_in
        self.n_out = n_out
        self.activation = {'relu': F.relu, 'sigmoid': F.sigmoid, 
'identity': F.identity}[activation]



    def __call__(self, x, train=True):
        h1 = F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)), train=train)
        if self.tied:
            return self.activation(F.linear(h1, F.transpose(self.l1.W), 
self.decoder_bias))
        else:
            return self.activation(self.l2(h1))

    def encode(self, x, train=True):
        return F.dropout(self.activation(self.l1(x)), train=train)

    def decode(self, x, train=True):
        if self.tied:
            return self.activation(F.linear(x, F.transpose(self.l1.W), 
self.decoder_bias))
        else:
            return self.activation(self.l2(x))

class StackedAutoEncoder(chainer.ChainList):
    def __init__(self, autoencoders):
        super(StackedAutoEncoder, self).__init__()
        for ae in autoencoders:
            self.add_link(ae)

    def __call__(self, x, train=True, depth=0):
        if depth == 0: depth = len(self)
        h = x
        for i in range(depth):
            h = self[i].encode(h, train=train)
        for i in range(depth):
            if i == depth-1: # do not use dropout in the output layer
                train = False
            h = self[depth-1-i].decode(h, train=train)
        return h

    def encode(self, x, train=True, depth=0):
        if depth == 0: depth = len(self)
        h = x
        for i in range(depth):
            h = self[i].encode(h, train=train)
        return h

    def decode(self, x, train=True, depth=0):
        if depth == 0: depth = len(self)
        h = x
        for i in range(depth):
            if i == depth-1: # do not use dropout in the output layer
                train = False
            h = self[depth-1-i].decode(h, train=train)
        return h

class Regression(chainer.Chain):
    def __init__(self, predictor):
        super(Regression, self).__init__(predictor=predictor)

    def __call__(self, x, t):
        y = self.predictor(x, True)
        self.loss = F.mean_squared_error(y, t)
        return self.loss

    def dump(self, x):
        return self.predictor(x, False)

initmodel = ''resume = ''
gpu = -1
epoch_pre = 20
epoch_fine = 20
batchsize = 100
noise = 0
optimizer = 'adam'
learningrate = 0.01
alpha = 0.001
unit = '1000, 500, 250, 2'
activation = 'sigmoid'
untied = False

batchsize = batchsize
n_epoch = epoch_pre
n_epoch_fine = epoch_fine

n_units = list(map(int, unit.split(',')))
activation = activation

mnist = fetch_mldata('MNIST original', data_home='.')
perm = np.random.permutation(len(mnist.data))
mnist.data = mnist.data.astype(np.float32) / 255
train_data = mnist.data[perm][:60000]
test_data = mnist.data[perm][60000:]

# prepare layers
aes = []
for idx in range(len(n_units)):
    n_in = n_units[idx-1] if idx > 0 else 28*28
    n_out = n_units[idx]
    ae = AutoEncoder(n_in, n_out, activation, tied = True)
    aes.append(ae)

# prepare train data for next layer
x = chainer.Variable(np.array(train_data))
train_data_for_next_layer = cuda.to_cpu(ae.encode(x, train=False))
```

Comment: The error indicates that the input shape of the array given to `F.linear` is wrong. See https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tips.html#how-do-i-fix-invalidtype-error for the details.

Answer (score 0):

The `InvalidType` error indicates that the input shape of the array given to `F.linear` is wrong.

```
Expect: x.shape[1] == W.shape[1]
Actual: 784 != 250
```

In this case, for the given input `x` and `W`, `F.linear` expects that 
 `x.shape[1]` is the same as `W.shape[1]`, but it does not.

For more detailed description of the error message, see https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/tips.html#how-do-i-fix-invalidtype-error to understand how to interpret that error message.